# Which subset of Unicode symbols should I use to mark special substrings in text?

Tags: java, unicode, localization

Our application sends `strings` which then shall be localized on `client side`. Sometimes those are `whole strings`, sometimes only `substring`, so we have to mark them. It would be the best if it only used Unicode as it wouldn't require any protocol changes.

**Example:**

```
"Length: (mark)10(mark)"
```

where 10 is length in cm but it should be converted so it is displayed as inches or mm.
Are Unicode special characters `(0xFFF0-0xFFFF)` right choice for marking such special substrings in text?

Comment: what are those "localized" texts? why don't just use the ones that are already in Unicode?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about preferences on localization in applications.

Comment: @Unihedron It is not as I am asking which subset of Unicode should I use to mark something in text. As you can see there is universal answer.

Comment: You asked "_Are Unicode special characters the right choice_", it's difficult to highlight what you meant as "_Which subset of Unicode characters should I use to mark something in text_". If you can clarify that by editing the question, please do so in hopes of getting your question reopened.

Comment: @Unihedron if I would have formed question like that you would say that I didn't do any research on that. But whatever I got the answer that I couldn't find on SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, code points in the [Specials block](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf) have their own uses. Using them for other purposes may result in unexpected effects. Even if you code all the processing yourself, the incoming data might contain those code points. It is of course possible to detect them and filter them out, but it is better to use code points that cannot clash with any assigned code points.

Use code points in the range U+FDD0..U+FDEF. They are designated as “noncharacters” and intended for use inside an application. See the Unicode FAQ section [Private-Use Characters, Noncharacters & Sentinels FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html).